# How to POST form data on page load without JS or submit button click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a specific use case where my page is on another domain inside an `iframe`.

I have to do a `HTTP POST` inside the `iframe` to a predefined URL(cross domain, Don't worry about CORS) so that the host can close the `iframe`

I could do this with JS hassle free.

How can i achieve this without JS (In case the JS is disabled) and without a submit button click.

Comment: What exactly triggers the upload? Any user interaction?

Comment: No user interaction

Comment: So, you have a page—I think you refer to as "host"— that contains and iframe that contains a form. And upon "page load" you need the form in the iframe to be posted. Right? *Question*: does the "page load" event occur on the "host" page or the iframe page? *Another question*: does "page load" happen if Javascript is turned off?

Comment: All i am concerned is about my page inside an iframe on another host and i need to perform a POST without user interaction and without JS

Comment: Does this help? [Pass an Event to an iframe from the parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28766463/2743458)